How to enable word level Confidence for MS Azure Speech to Text Service for Node JS
According to this, it's possible to get per word confidence levels in the JSON output for the Azure STT service. The issue is that I cannot seem to find out how to do this using the Node JS library (or if it's even possible).
Existing Code
Currently I have the following config in my STT class:
// Create the push audio input stream with the correct audio format
const audioFormat = speechSdk.AudioStreamFormat.getWaveFormatPCM(
    currentConfig.sampleRateHertz,
    16, // Bits per sample
    1   // Mono channel
);

this.audioStream = speechSdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream(audioFormat);

// Configure the speech settings
this.speechConfig = speechSdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(this.subscriptionKey, this.region);
this.speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = currentConfig.language;
// MORE CONFIG
this.speechConfig.outputFormat = speechSdk.OutputFormat.Detailed;

// Create the audio config from the push stream
this.audioConfig = speechSdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(this.audioStream);

// Create the speech recognizer
this.recognizer = new speechSdk.SpeechRecognizer(this.speechConfig, this.audioConfig);

I then have the following to recognize the audio in real time:
this.recognizer.recognizing = (s, e) => {
    console.debug("AzureProvider: JSON Result: ", e.results);

    if (e.result.reason === speechSdk.ResultReason.NoMatch) {
        console.warn("AzureProvider: No match found.");
        return;
    }

    let result = {
        text: e.result.text,
        score: e.result.confidence ? Math.round(e.result.confidence * 100) : 100,
    };

    if (this.results.length === this.maxResults) {
        this.results.shift();
    }

    this.results.push(result);
};

this.recognizer.recognized = (s, e) => {
    console.debug("AzureProvider: JSON Result: ", e.results);

    // Test if no match was found
    if (e.result.reason === speechSdk.ResultReason.NoMatch) {
        console.warn("AzureProvider: No final match found.");
        return;
    }

    let result = {
        text: this.postProcessTranscript(e.result.text),
        score: e.result.confidence ? Math.round(e.result.confidence * 100) : 100,
    };

    // Print to the console
    console.debug("AzureProvider: Final recognized result: ", result);
    this.emit('result', result);

    if (this.results.length === this.maxResults) {
        this.results.shift();
    }

    this.results.push(result);
};

Attempts for enabling word level confidence
To attempt to enable word level confidence, I tried adding the following config above (where the MORE CONFIG comment is):
this.speechConfig.setProperty("SpeechServiceResponse_RequestWordLevelConfidence", "true");
this.speechConfig.setProperty("SpeechServiceResponse_RequestWordLevelTimestamps", "true");
this.speechConfig.setProperty("SpeechServiceResponse_NBestList", "5");

I also tried adding the following:
this.speechConfig.setProperty("wordLevelConfidence", "true", speechSdk.ServicePropertyChannel.UriQueryParameter)

Neither work and I am at a loss...

Try setting speechConfig.setProperty(speechSdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_RequestWordLevelConfidence, "true") to get the word-level confidence.

I have successfully retrieved the word-level confidence by making a few changes to your code. I have configured setProperty as shown below.
speechConfig.setProperty(
    speechSdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_RequestWordLevelConfidence,
    "true"
);
speechConfig.setProperty(
    speechSdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_RequestWordLevelTimestamps,
    "true"
);


I have used fs.readFileSync to load the .wav file and pass it to the recognizer via AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput.

const  audioConfig = speechSdk.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(fs.readFileSync(audioFile));

app.js :
const speechSdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
const fs = require("fs");

const subscriptionKey = '<speechKey>';  
const region = '<speeckRegion>';  
const audioFile = 'audio/SPkam.wav';

const speechConfig = speechSdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region);
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
speechConfig.outputFormat = speechSdk.OutputFormat.Detailed;

speechConfig.setProperty(
    speechSdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_RequestWordLevelConfidence,
    "true"
);
speechConfig.setProperty(
    speechSdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_RequestWordLevelTimestamps,
    "true"
);

if (!fs.existsSync(audioFile)) {
    console.error("Audio file not found:", audioFile);
    process.exit(1);
}
const audioConfig = speechSdk.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(fs.readFileSync(audioFile));
const recognizer = new speechSdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
console.log("Starting speech recognition...");
recognizer.recognizing = (s, e) => {
};

recognizer.recognized = (s, e) => {
    if (e.result.reason === speechSdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        console.log("Recognized:", e.result.text);
        const resultJson = e.result;
        try {
            const parsedJson = JSON.parse(resultJson.privJson);
            console.log("Corrected JSON:", parsedJson);
            console.log("Transcription:", parsedJson.DisplayText);
            parsedJson.NBest.forEach(bestResult => {
                const words = bestResult.Words || [];
                console.log("Word-level confidence:");
                if (words.length > 0) {
                    words.forEach((word, index) => {
                        console.log(`  Word ${index + 1}: "${word.Word}"`);
                        console.log(`    Confidence: ${bestResult.Confidence}`);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("  No words found in this result.");
                }
                console.log(`  Overall confidence for this transcription: ${bestResult.Confidence}`);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to parse JSON:", error);
        }
    } else if (e.result.reason === speechSdk.ResultReason.NoMatch) {
        console.warn("No match found.");
    }
};

recognizer.canceled = (s, e) => {
    console.error(`Recognition canceled: ${e.errorDetails}`);
    recognizer.close();
    process.exit(1);
};

recognizer.sessionStopped = (s, e) => {
    console.log("Session stopped.");
    recognizer.close();
    process.exit(0);
};
recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();

Output :
I successfully got the word level confidence in the below output.




So upon looking at your code, it seems that you are simply printing the confidence for the NBest match rather than the individual words themselves. Is it possible to get the confidence level for the individual words like in the linked question?
